# Displaying field data of mysql table with selecting field name from the drop down list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I have the following code to populate field names together in a drop down list. I'd like to be able to display the contents of the selected field in a table on the page. Only one field name will be selected. So it will be single column table on the page. I couldn't find anything similar to this on the web. I'd be glad if someone can help me with this. thanks!

```
<?php 

$host = 'localhost'; 
$port = '3306'; 
$server = $host . ':' . $port; 
$user = 'root'; 
$password = ''; 
$link = count($t_tmp = explode(':', $server)) > 1 ? mysqli_connect($t_tmp[0], $user, $password, '', $t_tmp[1]) : mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Error: Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link)); 
} 
$database = 'mydb'; 
mysqli_select_db($link, $database); 
$query = 'select * from mytable'; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
if (!$result) { 
    $message = 'ERROR:' . mysqli_error($link); 
    return $message; 
} else { 
    $i = 0; 
     echo '<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">'; 
    while ($i < mysqli_field_count($link)) { 
        $meta =  
        mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i); 
        echo '<option>' . $meta->name . '</option>'; 
        $i = $i + 1; 
    } 
echo '</select>';
} 
mysqli_close($link); 
?>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

The options in the select box are all field names, not field values. What I need is to display field values when the field name is clicked/selected.

Comment: You do that after the user submits the form.

Comment: If you want to do it without submitting, you have to do it on the client in Javascript. PHP runs on the server.

Comment: yes, i am looking for a solution without submitting or submit button.

Comment: I added the necessary tags to my question now. thanks.

Comment: Why use `SELECT *` if you only want to display 1 column? That's a really bad habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help! I found my answer here: https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/307230-php-dropdown-menu-to-fetch-columnar-data/page-2#entry1558339

Here is the code:

```
<table class="tbresult">

<?php 

include ("confige.php");

$query = 'select * from employees'; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
if (!$result) { 
    $message = 'ERROR:' . mysqli_error($link); 
    return $message; 
} else { 
    $i = 0; 
    echo '<form name="selectSomething" action="" method="GET">';
     echo '<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"  onchange="this.form.submit()">'; 
    while ($i < mysqli_field_count($link)) { 
        $meta =  
        mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i); 
        echo '<option>' . $meta->name . '</option>'; 
        $i = $i + 1; 
    } 
echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';
} 

if(isset($_GET['mySelect'])) {
$myselect = $_GET['mySelect'];  // needs to be after the above check

$sql = "SELECT `$myselect` as mySelect FROM employees";  // add column alias
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);   

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["mySelect"] . "</td></tr>";

   }

      echo "</table>";


}

} else { echo "0 results"; }


mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`$country = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT country FROM countrys");`
`echo mysqli_num_rows($country);//counts the amount of rows in the db`

`echo '<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">';`

`while(mysqli_fetch_array($country)){`

`while ($i = mysqli_fetch_array($country)) {`

`echo '<option value="'.$i['country'].'">' . $i['country']. '</option>'`
 
   `}`
`echo '</select>';`

always works fine ;)

Comment: I need to select one field name from a list of field names. and it can be any of them. I don't know much about php, but your code is used to select one field from the table. There are many fields, and it can be any of them.

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.  Always explain how your suggestion works and why you feel it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an event handler on your select.

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  $.post('your-file.php', { 
    action: 'getOptionInfo',
    option: $('#mySelect option:selected').text()
  }, function(optionInfoHTML) {
    $('.table').html(optionInfoHTML);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwe55nm9/1/

Also, I reccomend building your select html and echo it as a whole, rather than over and over for every option. And just my preference, I would use a for loop. While loops always seem to get stuck in infinite loops.

```
... code to connect to database ...
switch ($_POST['action']) {
  case 'buildSelect':
    $options = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_field_count($link); $i++) { 
      $meta =  mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i); 
      $options += . '<option>' . $meta->name . '</option>';
    } 
    echo '<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">' . $options . '</select>';
    break;
  case 'getOptionInfo':
    echo "code to get info for $_POST['option']"
    break;
  default: echo 'Invalid action.'
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thanks, PoorlyWrittenCode. but I guess there is a misunderstanding. I have a dropdown list of field names from mytable, it is working. What I need is when an field name's clicked, its values in the database are displayed on the page.

Comment: For example, when dolor is selected in your example, its contents  in the mysql table should be displayed on the page. https://jsfiddle.net/3a4694j0/7/

Comment: How many options will you have? If it's just a few, you could build your table the same way you built the select and then use `.hide()` and `.show()` in your handler. If it's alot or unknown, you can use `$.post()` in your handler to retrieve the data from your server every time the select is changed.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how I would go about this. Note this requires you to `$.post()` with `action: 'buildSelect'` to create your select. An added step, but it makes the code cleaner and easier to follow. Also, I coded that in the comment box, so there's surely syntactical errors. Hopefully it points you in the right direction though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  With the code I have now, the page looks like this : https://ibb.co/e2uSYn but I can't and don't know how to display the contents of any selected field in the select box.  So basically I need code to get info which's a single column  for the selected field.

Comment: When you change the option selected, it posts data to your php file, which should echo back the data for that option. I can't say exactly how that would look since I don't know what your database looks like. Just a thought, you want the option text, not value, right? `<option value="">text</option>` The text is visible to the user, the value is not.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am confused with terminology. In the picture I shared, you can see the field/column names of mysql table in the drop down list. when one of these field names are selected, I woulld like to see all the data in the selected column/field.

Comment: `<select>` is the containing element. `<option>` is the thing you actually select. Are you saying you want the data to display in the text of the option? I originally read it as you have a separate table elsewhere to display the data.

Comment: I have one database, and one table. There are many fields in this table. You can see some of the field names in the drop down list in the picture I shared. I have the code to fetch the field names and list them in the drop down box. It is working fine. What I need is when a field name is selected/clicked in the drop down list, I'd like the selected field data to be displayed on the page. Since every field of the mysql table is one column, so it will be a single column data display on the page. I made a mocked example here:https://jsfiddle.net/ah2d5b4q/

Comment: Yeah, so we're on the same page. In my code above, you need to replace `"code to get info for $_POST['option']"` with the php code to retrieve the data from your sql table (something like `'SELECT ' . $_POST['option'] . ' FROM mytable'`).  `$_POST['option']` should be the text from the option selected. Whatever you echo back will be available in the `optionInfoHTML` argument of the callback.

Comment: I replaced the code with what you provided. but it doesn't work.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2326234fb3f21b57a7dc67cb8d3f74a8745a4665

Comment: That's why I said "something like". I don't have much experience with sql statements, so you'll have to research how to get the column of data you want from your table. (maybe https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp will help) Also, your sandbox notes `All functions that do not require disk, system or network access are whitelisted, others blacklisted.` Since sql requires network access, I don't think that will work. Also, also, you may want to escape anything from the `$_POST` variable to mitigate nefarious injections. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time.